Sort a field on an Access continuous form based on combobox text not combobox number
I have a list in a table "Task-TrainingStatus":
Id  Priority
1   Medium
2   Low
3   High
4   Lowest
5   N/A
6   Highest

My data table "Task-TrainingList" has:
Id PriorityLevel
1       3
2       3
3       6
4       2
5       1
6       2
7       4
8       5

I have a continuous form "TrainingList" that has a combobox "cboxPriority"
Control Source : PriorityLevel
Row Source : SELECT [Task-TrainingStatus].[ID], [Task-TrainingStatus].[Priority] FROM [Task-TrainingStatus] ORDER BY [Priority]; 
Bound Column: 1
Column Count: 2
Column Widths: 0";1"

The combobox acts as expected, it shows low, lowest, Medium, etc...
I have a label "lblPriority" with an on click event (simplified)

Private Sub lblPriority_Click()
    Me.OrderBy = "PriorityLevel"
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub

The problem is that it sorts based on the numeric Id so I get:
Medium
Low
High
Lowest
N/A
Highest

and I want it to sort by the text
High
Highest
Low
Lowest
Medium
N/A

The sort is based on the underlying table value and I can't figure out how to get from there to the text value.
How do I do it?

TIA
Edit - October 13, 2024.  I'm not sure if this goes here or in the comments.  I apologize if I have it in the wrong spot.
I made the changes suggested in answer 1.  The form sorts correctly but now the recordset is not updateable.
When I take the join out of the sql, the from is updateable (but does not sort correctly).
This is the full sql
 SELECT [Task-TrainingList].IDtodo, [Task-TrainingList].Title, [Task-TrainingList].Description, [Task-TrainingList].DateEntered, [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel, [Task-TrainingList].WhoAmI, [Task-TrainingList].WhatAmI, [Task-TrainingList].Done, [Task-TrainingStatus].Priority FROM [Task-TrainingList] INNER JOIN [Task-TrainingStatus] ON [Task-TrainingList].prioritylevel = [Task-TrainingStatus].ID;

How do I make it sortable and updateable?

Your form needs to use a query as the record source:
SELECT [Task-TrainingList].ID, 
       [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel, 
       [Task-TrainingStatus].Priority
FROM [Task-TrainingList] 
INNER JOIN [Task-TrainingStatus] ON [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel = [Task-TrainingStatus].ID;

You can then set the OrderBy property on the form to Priority or as an alternative, you can sort the data in the query:
SELECT [Task-TrainingList].ID, 
       [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel, 
       [Task-TrainingStatus].Priority
FROM [Task-TrainingList] 
INNER JOIN [Task-TrainingStatus] ON [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel = [Task-TrainingStatus].ID
ORDER BY [Task-TrainingStatus].Priority;


I am confused.  If I use that join I will only get records 1-6 of the Task-TrainingList.  I want to show all of the records in Task-TrainingList, I just want them ordered by the priority.

I must apologise. There was an error in the INNER JOIN which I have now corrected in my answer above. [Task-TrainingList].ID was changed to [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel.

No need to apologize, I appreciate the help.  It sorts, but only records that actually have a priority already assigned are included in the SELECT.   I don't get why making the record source a query helps.  In theory it should result in the same set of records

Without physically changing table Task-TrainingList to include the Priority text (you should not do that), a query is the only way of introducing the field Priority as a sortable value. To return all records in table Task-TrainingList simply change the query so that INNER JOIN becomes LEFT JOIN.

You may also want to consider setting a DefaultValue on field [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel (would suggest zero) and creating a corresponding record in table Task-TrainingStatus to designate an Undefined value. You could possibly use your N/A record but I would personally give it an Id of 0 (zero) which should then correspond to a DefaultValue value of 0 (zero) on field [Task-TrainingList].PriorityLevel.

Thank you, Thank you.  It all works now.  I added the default which also solved the join issue because now every record has a corresponding priority.

I made the changes suggested in answer 1. The form sorts correctly but now the recordset is not updateable. When I take the join out of the sql, the from is updateable (but does not sort correctly).
Did some searching around the internet.  Many of the answers related to primary key.  My tables all have an autonumber field and I usually make that the primary key.  I went into Task-TrainingStatus and changed the primary key from the autonumber to the Id that I used for the combobox and it works!
